# MS Access 2010: Is it possible to link datasheet subforms

Tags: forms, ms-access, subform

Any help is appreciated with the following case with minimum coding:

I am using MS Access 2010 where I have many unrelated tables (all in tabs).The main form has no source. For instance (one of the tabs), I have a sub-form as datasheet where it drills down to its related record in the hierarchy of the same table (the + sign which opens other records in the same table).

`Example:
CLASSPATH 
(pathid, code, parentcode)
1,TOP,null
2,SUB,TOP
3,SUBSUB,SUB
...`

I also have another datasheet below that which is referenced by the pathid

`CLASSPROP
(pathid,propname)
1,TEST
2,TEST2
.....`

The requirement is when the CLASSPATH record is opened (current record in the hiearachy), I need to fetch and have the current record of the sub-datasheet of the CLASSPROP using the PATHID link without referring to any master unbound main form due to the nature of the tabbed main form which is general for many sub-forms/datasheets.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Think this is what you want to do:
[Synchronize subforms](http://www.fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/Forms/Synchronize/LinkedSubforms.asp)

Be aware this method can be problematic for entering new records.